# Change in Length of an element of spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

Lets say that we have a spring, with spring constant k. It has an orignal length of $l_1$ and after stretching it a length of $l_2$. Now lets take and element of length of $\Delta$l.When the spring was stretched I wanted to find out how much does this element stretch. Online I found a answer which said that as all elements stretch and equal length. $\frac{\Delta l }{\Delta y}$=$\frac{l_1}{l_2}$. Now I did not really get why this was happening. I would like a answer with a mathematical approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay we have quantity called Youngs Modulus.

Let us take an elementary part of the spring with original length **dl**.Let us apply a force **F** on the spring which causes an expansion **dx** .Let the cross sectional area be **A**.Then Young Modulus is

Y = Stress / Strain = (F/A)/ (dx/dl)

Now Youngs modulus is same for all parts of the spring as it depends on material which is same for whole spring .
So the quantity on the right must also be same for all elements.

[image]

Notice the above diagram. Notice how equal and opposite forces act on the ends.This is true for any dl element . This means that equal force act on each element.This is based on Newtons third law considering any element dl as our body.Further cross section are is same.

Therefore dx/dl must be same for all elements . Similar arguments may be made for whole spring.

Therefore ,
dx/dl = total elongation / total length .

Notice these arguments are valid as long as spring is uniform.

---

P.S. This can be understood using symmetry too.Each element must elongate equally as all elements are essentially same and we do not have any reason to give special treatment to only a few elements.